# Posting an url-encoded xml to the url

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Hello I have a xml document in string that I am trying to post to a url.

```
 string xml = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/test.txt"));
      myurl=(uri+Server.UrlEncode(xml));
       Response.Write("<a input type="hidden" name="cxml-urlencoded" value="myurl"></a>");
```

The Response.Write is not working as it is not properly written i get red wiggly underline starting hidden saying expected ")" 
Any ideas how to go about it?
Thanks

Comment: Use the '@' character and double your quotes: `Response.Write(@"<a input type=""hidden"" name=""cxml-urlencoded"" value=""myurl""></a>");` or escape your double quotes: `Response.Write("<a input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cxml-urlencoded\" value=\"myurl\"></a>");` Vote to close; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string

Comment: May I suggest, however, that a more readable solution would involve the following: `Response.Write(String.Format("<a input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cxml-urlencoded\" value=\"{0}\"></a>", myurl));` as currently, you aren't concatenating the variable `myurl` in your string anyway.

Comment: Actually I have a xml document that i need to post to a url using input= hidden name=cxml-url-encoded from c# whats the best way

Comment: " –  dash" Isn't that redundant? Waltzing Ma~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the mini-library I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570950/298754).  You'd use it like:

```
HTTP_Post(uri, Server.UrlEncode(xml), DataType.XML)
```

I don't know if it'd handle the specific field name you need to use, though.