# Posting string xml values to a url

Tags: c#, .net, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posting an url-encoded xml to the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904346/posting-an-url-encoded-xml-to-the-url)

I am trying to post xml document to a url that has a hidden field called "hidden1"

```
string xml = "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
</catalog>";


string  myurl=(uri+Server.UrlEncode(str1));
      Response.Write(@"<a input type=""hidden"" name=""hidden1"" value=""myurl""></a>"); 
      Response.Close();
```

It didnt work because i think myurl string is not being passed correctly. Any ideas how to do it right way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the escape character ('\') before the double quotes for the following lines:

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<catalog>
   <book id=\"bk101\">
   ...
```